# passportJS req.user is undefined (not deserializing)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, web, passport.js

I have followed the steps described in the documentation of passportJS to configure local authentication. I pretty much copy-pasted their code to test if it works.

However, I now have 2 (related?) problems:

1. deserializeUser is never being called
2. req.user is undefined

I tried pretty much everything (changing the middleware orders, putting       withCredentials: true on the client side, ...) that is mentioned in related posts, but nothing seems to work. Does someone maybe see what I'm doing wrong here?

**index.js**

```
app.use(express.json()); // to send data to the database
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // location of the react app
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cookieParser("secretcode"));
app.use(passport.initialize());
config(passport);


app.post("/login",   passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureMessage: true }),
function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/~' + req.user.username);
});

app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user); 
});
```

**config.js**

```
export const config = (passport) => {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function verify(username, password, cb) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [ username ], function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' }); }
  
      bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { return cb(err); }
        if (result === true) {
          return cb(null, user[0]);
        }
        return cb(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' });
      });
    });
  }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      return cb(null, user.id);
    });
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [ id ], function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Do you get any failure messages from `failureMessage: true` at all?

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* that your problem may be because you have not included `app.use(passport.authenticate('session'))`. Try that.

You can also debug further by passing a path into the `ensureLogIn` middleware as I've had problems with that in the past. It helps debug if you know what is being redirected.

Please find a working barebones attached here for a working passport-local and express example without all of the bloat. I think comparing this with your application would be the best bet.

Let me know if this helps.

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local')
const session = require('express-session')
const ensureLogIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const ensureLoggedIn = ensureLogIn('/not-logged-in')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.use(passport.authenticate('session'))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ hello: 'world' })
})

app.all('/secure', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => res.json({ is: 'secure' }))

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'username',
  passwordField: 'password',
  session: true
},
function (username, password, cb) {
  if (username !== 'hello' && password !== 'world') {
    console.log('verify', username, password, 'fail')
    return cb(null, false)
  } else {
    console.log('verify', username, password, 'pass')
    return cb(null, { username: 'hello' })
  }
}
))

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    console.log('serializeUser', user)
    cb(null, user)
  })
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    console.log('deserializeUser', user)
    return cb(null, user)
  })
})
app.post('/logins',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    // successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login-fail',
    failureMessage: true
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log('logged in', req.params, req.user)
    // res.send('Logged in')
    res.redirect('/secure')
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I eventually had to prevent the default submit action by doing event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the`app.post('signup')` function, I was facing a similar problem, It was because the `newUser` object I was passing to passport js, didn't had the user details.

```
req.login(newUser, function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  res.redirect('/user/feed');
});
```

As I was using `Model.collection.insertOne` in MongoDB, which was not returning the user object.
Hence things were not working.
Instead when I used `Model.create`, things went fine.

Answer (score 0):

After reading documentation to no avail, I found a work around for those finding `undefined` by storing the user in a cookie

```js
authRouter.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("user", req.user);

    res.redirect("http://localhost:5173");
  } 
);
```

You can now get the user data using

```js
authRouter.get("/api/user", (req, res) => {
  const userData = req.cookies.user;
  res.json(userData);
});
```

In the frontend using react

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/user")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```